# CUDA - Creating objects in kernel and using them at host

Tags: c++, cuda, nvidia

I need to use polymorphism in my kernels. The only way of doing this is to create those objects on the device (to make a virtual mehod table available at the device). Here's the object being created

```
class Production {
    Vertex * boundVertex;
}


class Vertex {
    Vertex * leftChild;
    Vertex * rightChild;
}
```

Then on the host I do:

```
Production* dProd;
cudaMalloc(&dProd, sizeof(Production *));
createProduction<<<1,1>>>(dProd);
```

where

```
__global__ void createProduction(Production * prod) {
    prod = new Production();
    prod->leftChild = new Vertex();
    prod->rightChild = new Vertex();
}
```

The question is how do I get both left and right vertices of the production created on the device back on the host? I know using pointers in classes makes them very hard to handle but... no other way of creating such tree structure.

Comment: Your question is not clear.  Doesn't the method you have depicted already create the left and right vertices on the device?  Are you asking "once created, how to I move the left and right vertices back to the host?"  I think your setup of `dProd` is a little odd, but that doesn't seem to be impacting anything.

Comment: I would like to dereference leftChild and rightChild back on the host. They are created on the device and I need them on the host.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do that.

The host runtime and driver memory management APIs can't be used to access allocations made on the runtime heap using `new` or `malloc`. There is no way for the host to copy those `Vertex`instances from the device.